# Get data-bind value in jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout js to set a span value.

HTML Code

```
<span id="spnQStreamChat" data-bind="text: $data.OnLineUserName"></span>
```

this is working fine and showing user name on the UI.

I am trying to get that value from js file.
by using below code

```
alert($(this).attr('data-bind'));
```

this is serving result like this **text: $data.OnLineUserName** .  I want the username assigned by me.

In UI its showing Bhagirathi but in js its showing the content present in the data-bind

how to get the Name(means: Bhagirathi) in js file

please help to solve this problem

thanks in advance

[EDIT]

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-mini", function (e) {
    alert(ko.contextFor($('.btn-mini')[0]).$data.OnLineUserName);
    try {
        var connectionId = chatHub.server.getUserConnectionId($(this).attr('data-bind').username, sessionUserName);
    }
    catch (e) {
        //error
    }
});
```

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the knockout context for element with

```
ko.contextFor($('#spnQStreamChat').get(0))
```

this will return an an object like

```
ko.bindingContext {$parents: Array[1], $root: ViewModel, ko: Object, $data: SomeObject, $parentContext: ko.bindingContext…}
```

where $data is your $data object. So to get the name you need something like

```
ko.contextFor($('.button.btn.c_btn').get(0)).$data.OnLineUserName()
```

This way is more useful when you need to get $data object. Otherwise you can just get the 'text' of a span with jQuery

Comment: $('.button.btn.c_btn').get(0) what this means?

Comment: @user1926138
$('.button.btn.c_btn').get(0) same as $('.button.btn.c_btn')[0]
ko.contextFor(node) receives only one node but jQuery selector returns an array

Comment: what does that means ?

Comment: select the first element of the array

Comment: yes but i want to select the last element 

how could i know the number

Comment: please check i am using like this its working fine and showing always 1st name