# can't get the attribute value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, svg

I'm using svg and i'm using `knockout` in my svg application and its working fine very well. But i'm using `data-bind` to change the textContent of the `svg text` element, after i used data-bind to the attribute, i can't get the value of that attribute using `text.attributes['text'].value`.

**Edited :**
My text is element is like this.

```
<text data-bind=\'{style: fill:viewModel.marks()>50?"green":"red"},text: "UserName :" + viewModel.userName()\'></text>
```

How can i get the text attribute value before applybinding?

**NOTE :** I have found this [Get data-bind value in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019239/get-data-bind-value-in-jquery) link but this `ko.contextFor` method is not working for me.

Any suggestions should be appreciated.

Regards,
KarthiK.

Comment: You may need to have a listener of some sort in the SVG (if that is possible). The SVG could be getting compiled and the data-bind is happening at runtime.

Comment: You can get it through jQuery like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/e83Zb/2/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `attributes` to access the text value. You can use the `textContents` property, for example:

**HTML**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
     <text x="0" y="15" fill="blue" data-bind='text: userName()'></text>
</svg>
<br>
<button data-bind='click: test'>Test</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = {
    userName : ko.observable("Jones"),
    test : function() {
        var t = document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0],
            s = t.textContent;
        alert(s);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/e83Zb/5/

Comment: I forget to mention that, i need to get the text attribute value before applybinding.

Comment: Do you mean, you need the value of `userName`, before calling ko.applyBindings()? Just use `viewModel.userName()` for that. Please add more sample code to the question so we can help you.

Comment: I need the value of the text attribute(not userName alone, i need the whole value of text attribute like "UserName : Jones") before calling ko.applybinding and i just edited my code.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that is possible. The closest you will get is this: http://jsfiddle.net/e83Zb/6/. But to resolve the username you will have to evaluate the viewModel.